# Retrieve a data from an ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I have this variable:

```
protected ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The data is in this form:

```
data = date + ": " + y + "L/100KM "+ " " + value1 + "dt "+ value2 + "KM\n";
```

I want to retrieve a data `value1` from it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just split on whitespace like this:

```
String[] result = data.split(" ");
```

your value1 should be third item in this array, so you can access it by calling:

```
String value1 = result[2];
```

Or if you wrote this code why the hell would you try to get value from a string where you just put that value yourself. :)

Comment: `Or if you wrote this code why the hell would you try to get value from a string where you just put that value yourself. :)` Good question ;): In fact, i want to store this value1 just before deleting it. I plan to make a sum of all money added in the file, then if a user delete a line(data) from this file, the preference should also delete it.Clear :) ? So your answer may solve my problem ?

Comment: I tried to implement it but that's impossible. data variable is in the other class, delete a data is in the other. What to do what to do :\\ ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not understanding your idea.

Comment: If your data has a specific format you can do couple of things. 1. Use regular expressions.     2. Split your string on space and extract  value1

Comment: @JayP: the old rule says - if you have a problem, which can be solved with a regex, then now you have 2 problems ;-). But yes, it's a viable option. Although a good answer will provide the regex itself. If regex is available in android per ce.